# PySide: How to get the layout containing a given widget?

Tags: python, pyside

From a given widget, is it possible to get the layout that contains it?

I'm doing a dynamic form, and my widget hierarchy looks like:

```
QDialogBox
|- QVBoxLayout
  |- QHBoxLayout 1
    |- Widget 1
    |- Widget 2
    |- ...
  |- QHBoxLayout 2
    |- Widget 1
    |- Widget 2
    |- ...
  |- ...
```

If I receive a signal from `Widget 1` or `Widget 2`, I can identify it using `sender()` function. I'd like to be able to adjust some properties of other widgets on the same line. How can I get a reference to the `QHBoxLayout` containing a given widget?

`parent()` property gives me the `QDialogBox`, since the parent of a widget cannot be a layout. `layout()` property gives me `None`, since it refers to the contained layout, not the containing layout.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, the following should work (I tested on a similar setup):

```
# Starting from Widget_1 get a list of horizontal layouts contained by QVBoxLayout
# Widget_1.parent() returns the QDialogBox
# .layout() returns the containing QVBoxLayout
# children returns layouts in QVBoxLayout, including QHBoxLayout 1-N
# if you know that there are only QHBoxLayouts, you don't need to filter
hlayouts = [layout for layout in Widget_1.parent().layout().children()
            if type(layout) == PySide.QtGui.QHBoxLayout]

def layout_widgets(layout):
    """Get widgets contained in layout"""
    return [layout.itemAt(i).widget() for i in range(layout.count())]

# then find hlayout containing Widget_1
my_layout = next((l for l in hlayouts if Widget_1 in layout_widgets(l)), None)
```

I'm using next() to find the first layout containing your widget (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2748753/532513). For more readability you could use a for loop, but next() is cleaner.

Comment: Yes, I ended doing something similar. But I was wondering if there would be a better way than looping through all the layout items.